# R Error: comparison of these types is not implemented. Occurs when attempting to filter rows based on matching columns

Tags: r, filter, data.table, comparison, matching

I feel like maybe I'm missing a package. This code worked fine on my old laptop, but when I transferred everything to my desktop computer, it would not cooperate.

I merged data from two sources, each with a column that has US states' 2-digit identifiers:

```
distarea <- merge(x=femadata2, y=censdata2, by = ("CTYNAME"), all=FALSE)
```

I only want to see rows where that states in each of these columns match:

```
distarea2 <- distarea[distarea$FEMAState==distarea$STNAME, ]
```

After running this line, I receive this error:

> Error in distarea$FEMAState == distarea$STNAME :
> comparison of these types is not implemented
> In addition: Warning message:
> In `[.data.frame`(distarea, distarea$FEMAState == distarea$STNAME,  :
> Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.table") for "=="

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit your post to include output of `dput(head(femadata2))` and `dput(head(censdata2))` to share first few rows of data.  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Those are `factor` columns.  We can convert to `character` class

```
  distarea[as.character(distarea$FEMAState)== as.character(distarea$STNAME), ]
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: @BenjaminCallesen it is not possible to get same error, as we convert to `character`.  The error you showed is based on `factor` incompatibility.

Comment: Sorry, I ran it again, but now it generate a blank table.

Comment: @BenjaminCallesen Are you trying to filter elementwise.  Can you show a small example with `dput`

Comment: I'm taking a course on R, and still pretty new. If I enter `distarea[as.character(distarea$FEMAState)== as.character(distarea$STNAME), ]` nothing filters. I tried `distarea2 <- distarea[as.character(distarea$FEMAState)== as.character(distarea$STNAME), ]` which generates a blank distarea2

Comment: @BenjaminCallesen If you don't get anything, then I think the values are not matching in each row.  `==` is doing an elementwise comparison i.e. row1 element is compared to row1 of the second column, and so on

Comment: I can see matching values when I view the table, plus this worked fine on my old Linux laptop, but the error only starting occurring on my Mac desktop.

Comment: @BenjaminCallesen Can you show the values of `head(as.character(distarea$FEMAState))` and `head(as.character(distarea$STNAME))`

Comment: `> head(as.character(distarea$FEMAState))`
[1] "SC" "IA" "IA" "IA" "IA" "MO"

Comment: What are the values of STNAME

Comment: `head(as.character(distarea$STNAME))`[1] "c(\"SC\", \"KY\", \"OK\", \"IA\", \"MO\", \"KY\", \"OK\", \"IA\", \"MO\", \"KY\", \"OK\",

Comment: @BenjaminCallesen I thiink you have a `list` column in 'STNAME' that got converted to a single string.  Probably have to check the `str(censdata2)` and `str(femadata2)` before the merge